2018: a year in moderation
It's New Year's Day in Stack Exchange land...
A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
-- A Theory of Moderation

While there certainly are Moderators here, a significant amount of the moderation is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.
As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Quantitative Finance breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  5          9
Users destroyed                                  23          0
Users deleted                                    11          0
Users contacted                                  12          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           119        466
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                8         92
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         17        115
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               13        228
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                16      1,624
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               39      1,529
Questions reopened                               10          0
Questions protected                               0          1
Questions migrated                                9          0
Questions flagged⁴                                0        150
Questions closed                                322        238
Question flags handled⁴                          88         62
Posts unlocked                                    1          3
Posts undeleted                                   4         45
Posts locked                                      0         17
Posts deleted⁵                                  167      1,359
Posts bumped                                      0      1,756
Escalations to the CM team                        2          0
Comments flagged                                  0        448
Comments deleted⁶                                53      1,283
Comment flags handled                            86        362
Answers flagged                                   1        318
Answer flags handled                            290         29
All comments on a post moved to chat              1          0

Footnotes
¹ "Community" here refers both to the membership of Quantitative Finance without diamonds next to their names, and to the automated systems otherwise known as user #-1.
² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.
³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.
⁴ Includes close flags (but not close or reopen votes).
⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.
⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).
Wishing you all a happy new year...
